# Merge HTML TABLE ROWS if condition true

Tags: javascript

I fetched data from Mysql for a table. Each row has 5 cell.

If the 4th cell values of two rows are the same then I want to merge those rows.

I tried using javascript arrays but I couldn't merge the rows. Can anyone share their ideas or send me any sample code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "merge rows"? Try giving an example: what do you have, and what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

I was like posting a picture, but because im new and doesnt have reput, it was not uploaded...
well, [here the link of the photo](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/40/answerma.jpg/)

If that's what you asking for... I have a kinda long code.. i dont know if it is efficient but its working for me

```
int itemsize = 5; //number of rows that is expected to be in merged
for(int item=0; i<itemsize ; i++){//this jsp
%>
  <tr>
    <td><%=value%></td>
    <td><%=value%></td>
    <%
      if(itemsize > 1 && item==0){ //if the itemsize more than 1, and it is the first row, it will put a rowspan that has the value of the itemsize or the number of row to be merged
      %>
        <td rowspan='<%=itemsize %>'><%=value%></td>
        <td rowspan='<%=itemsize %>'><%=value%></td>
        <td rowspan='<%=itemsize %>'><%=value%></td>
      <%
      }else if(itemsize > 1 && item>0){
       //on the second loop this will be executed but bcoz we have rowspan, <td> should be eliminated on the succeeding row*
      }else{ // but if there is only one row to be displayed, no rowspan is needed, so ordinary <td will be written..
      %>
        <td><%=value%></td>
        <td><%=value%></td>
        <td><%=value%></td>          
      <%
      }
    %>
  </tr>
<%
}
```

**EDITED:**

This is my new code. i made a sample using php. try to run it. Sorry for the code, its my first PHP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
    body{ font-family: tahoma, Arial; font-size: 9pt;}
    table {border-collapse:collapse; font: tahoma, Arial 9pt;}
    table th{font-family: tahoma, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:9pt; width:75px; background-color:#999; color:#000; text-transform:uppercase;}
    table th, td{ padding:4px 6px; text-transform:capitalize;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" bordercolor="#000000"> 
    <thead>
        <th style="width:10px; text-align:right">Count</th>
      <th>Detail 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
      <th>Head 3</th>
      <th>Head 4</th>
      <th>Head 5</th>
      <th>Head 6</th>
      <th>Detail 2</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>   
            <?php               
                $arr_detail_1 = array("angelo", "philip", "raymond", "jonathan", "pedro");
                $arr_detail_2  = array("Cavite", "Laguna", "Quezon", "Japan", "Surigao");
                $arr_detail_3 = array("10-dec", "11-Sep", "12-Feb", "22-July", "15-Oct");
                $arr_detail_4  = array("Pink", "blue", "Green", "White", "Purple");
                $arr_detail_5  = array("Computer", "Door Lock", "Pencil", "Cup", "Jeans");

        $a=array("screw");
        $b=array("ball","paper","Big","Liquid","id");
        $c=array("Sewing");
        $d=array("Running","Biking","Swimming");
        $e=array("Tree","planting","root","fruits","Rain","Grass");

        $f=array("driver");
        $g=array("Pen","bag","Brother","eraser","lace");
        $h=array("machine");
        $i=array("barefoot","with no bike","technique");
        $j=array("planting","tree","crops","bearig-trees","Forest","Hopper");

        $arr1 = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
                $arr2 = array($f, $g, $h, $i, $j);              


            $rowcount = 1;
                for ($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++){
                 // echo "The number is " . $i . "<br />";

                 $temp_arr_1 = $arr1[$i];
                 $temp_arr_2 = $arr2[$i];
                 for($x=0; $x<count($temp_arr_1); $x++){

                     ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><?php echo $rowcount; ?>.</td>
              <td><?php echo $temp_arr_1[$x]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $temp_arr_2[$x]; ?></td>
              <?php
                            $span_count = count($temp_arr_1);
              if($span_count>1 && $x==0){

                                ?>
                  <td rowspan="<?php echo count($temp_arr_1);?>"><?php echo $arr_detail_1[$i]; ?></td>
                  <td rowspan="<?php echo count($temp_arr_1);?>"><?php echo $arr_detail_2[$i]; ?></td>
                  <td rowspan="<?php echo count($temp_arr_1);?>"><?php echo $arr_detail_3[$i]; ?></td>
                  <td rowspan="<?php echo count($temp_arr_1);?>"><?php echo $arr_detail_4[$i]; ?></td>
                  <td rowspan="<?php echo count($temp_arr_1);?>"><?php echo $arr_detail_5[$i]; ?></td>
                                <?php
                            }else if($span_count>1 && $x>0){
                                //
                            }else{
                                ?>
                  <td><?php echo $arr_detail_1[$i]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $arr_detail_2[$i]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $arr_detail_3[$i]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $arr_detail_4[$i]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $arr_detail_5[$i]; ?></td>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tr>
                     <?php
                     $rowcount++;
                    }
                }
      ?>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

i did use array to act as dbase... ;] and do the code in way like i do it with JSP so i hope you'll understand. im really new at php. even in java, im not sure if what im doing is correct! i code as long as it run, even if its slow.. but im trying to fix that! good luck to your project evangeline.

Comment: you're very much welcome. im glad to know i did help someone.. yehey! thanks too.

Comment: hi i need the same output. can u give me elaborate details. i have some doubts on above code

Comment: with the example ive written, it was actually the second loop. my project was about po monitoring, so with every po, there can be atleast 1 to lots of item in it.. the po number, date, client, and other details will be the the <td> to merged and the number of items are the determinant pof how many rows are going to be merge.. ill try to post another sample but in JSP.. dont know PHP.. still studying it!

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your response. But i done this using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A really quick sample if you did want to do it in javascript for some reason:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="2" id="aTable">
        <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>V</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Third</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Third</td>
            <td>E</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MergeCommonRows(table, columnIndexToMerge){
            previous = null;
            cellToExtend = null;
            table.find("td:nth-child("+columnIndexToMerge+")").each(function(){
                jthis = $(this);
                content = jthis.text()
                if(previous == content){
                    jthis.remove();
                    if(cellToExtend.attr("rowspan") == undefined){
                        cellToExtend.attr("rowspan", 2);
                    }
                    else{
                        currentrowspan = parseInt(cellToExtend.attr("rowspan"));
                        cellToExtend.attr("rowspan", currentrowspan+1);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    previous = content;
                    cellToExtend = jthis;
                }
            });
        };

        MergeCommonRows($("#aTable"), 1);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This works nice but just add parseInt around currentrowspan = parseInt(cellToExtend.attr("rowspan"))  -  otherwise you will get wired results

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to use javascript. First of all, some users may have deactivated js, or even not available (eg mobile phone browser).

I suggest to get the data from mysql, loop through them in php (if you use php), copy the data to a new array while doing any necessary merging and then print the new "correct" array.

Is it php that you are using? The sample code you need, has to be server side (eg php).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Am using PHP only. Can you provide sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should give the last cell in the first row `rowspan="2"` and omit the last cell in the next row.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>some value</td>
        <td>some value</td>
        <td>some value</td>
        <td>some value</td>
        <td rowspan="2">some value</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>some value</td>
        <td>some value</td>
        <td>some value</td>
        <td>some value</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```